# Is there notation for a set as a generated series?

Tags: notation

For summation of a series I can write

$$
x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_N
$$

but this much more compact notation is typically used:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N x_i
$$

On the other hand I often see sets expressed as

$$
X = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N\}
$$

but is there a more compact representation like with summation that's commonly used?

Comment: You can write $X= \lbrace x_i \mid 1 \leq i \leq N \rbrace$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe would I not also need to specify that $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: You can, but I would tend to say that this is implicit in the given notation (like in the summation one).

Comment: Right, because it's a subscript. Good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different notations that avoid "...", which is done by making the indices more explicit:

$$\{x_n\ |\ 1\leqslant n \leqslant N \}\tag 1$$

which has the ambiguity that the index set could be, say, the real numbers in that interval.  This occurs much less frequently than natural or integral indices, but it's still possible.  To be completely unambiguous, one can use

$$\{x_n\ |\ n\in [1,N]\cap\Bbb Z\}\tag 2$$

The advantage of this notations is that one can add more conditions like $x_n\in\Bbb R$ etc.

---

A similar notation is

$$\{x_n\}_1^N \quad\text{ or }\quad \{x_n\}_{n=1}^N \quad\text{ or }\quad \{x_n\}_{n\in[1,N]} \tag 3$$

where the 2nd and 3rd one can be used if there are other symbols involved and to point out that the index is named $n$.  A similar notation is sometimes used for (sub)sequences or tuples, like $(a_n)_1^N$.

---

Then there is the notation

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^N \{x_n\} \tag 4$$

This notation you will mostly encounter if the union is over sets.  Using it for elements requires to turn the elements into sets by enclosing them in `{}`, which is additional work, and the sub- and superscripts make it less preferable in running text.  Again, there is more than one way to indicate which indices are used like $1\leqslant n \leqslant N$ with the same ambigiutly like for $(1)$.

Comment: I wouldn't call $\bigcup_{n=1}^N \{x_n\}$ a "notation" for the set. I'd say it's an operation that has that set as a result.